# Hazelcast query to get Map based on keyset and predicate

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I have a hazelcast IMAP which looks like

```
IMAP = key -> val1, val2, val3
```

indexed on val1, val2
I am trying to get say `key->val2` given the set of Keys

```
hzObj.getMap("testMap").getAll(keys.toSet.asJava)
which returns the key->val1, val2, val3
```

Need help to write predicate which says to return only key->val2
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@nocturnal, please see example usage below:

`imap.project(Projections.singleAttribute("val2"), Predicates.in("__key", new String[]{"key1, key2"}));`

One important note, that'll require you to define an index on key as well.

Since this will be using query threads, you can also use `imap.getAll(Set keys)` instead & then just convert it to Collection of `val2`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your use case correctly, You can use [projections](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.10.3/manual/html-single/index.html#projections) to strip down result objects of a query in order to reduce redundant network traffic.

Comment: I am trying to find a good example to use projections not able to. Can you please help me with an example?

Comment: you can take a look at the docs http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.10.4/manual/html-single/index.html#projections and also the code samples for that in the related repo: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/distributed-map/projections